# How do you select which build target to debug?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019, multitargeting

If I am multitargeting a project to .Net Core 3.1 and .Net Framework 4.8 and I select *Debug | Start Debugging*, Visual Studio 2019 starts a debugging session with the .Net Framework build target.

How can I get it to launch the .Net Core build target instead?

Here is my test project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFrameworks>net48;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And here is the test code:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #if NET48
                Console.WriteLine(".Net Framework");
            #else
                Console.WriteLine(".Net Core");
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

There are no other files in the project. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.2.

Comment: Note that the "start debug" button on the toolbar has a dropdown.  Click it to select the target.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, looks like my toolbar has been customised and it doesn't have the "start debug" button. I'll have to try and add it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to make it obvious, If you click the dropdown next to your start debug toolbar item, you will see your targeting options

[image]

<sub>***Note** : I am trying to find the actual documentation for this... zilch*</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, I seem to have a customised toolbar without that option. I'm trying to add it to my toolbar - I've tried adding (from the Debug category) "Start Debug Target" and "Start / Continue" but neither of those have the dropdown. Do you happen to know the name of the command I need to add?

Comment: @MatthewWatson is should be just in the toolbar called `Standard`, arg trying to find the documentation on this thing is impossible

Comment: OK I found "Debug Target" on the Standard toolbar. Now I just need to work out how to add that to the customised toolbar (which was customised nearly two years ago...)

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah that's the part I was struggling with

Comment: It looks like Microsoft forgot to make it so you can add that item to a custom toolbar. Meh.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i could add a new menu item to the drop on the debug item (strange) but i couldn't add the debug target dropdown. if you get a a solution post an answer, i am sure it would useful for a lot of people

Comment: Yes, this is beginning to annoy me now. :)

Comment: I think you've answered my question - The question of how to add that command to a custom toolbar is a different one, so I'll ask a different question for that.

Comment: Make sure that you've selected a single startup project and have defined one or more profiles in Project Properties > Debug > General > Open Debug Launch Profile UI. I noticed that if I had multiple startup projects enabled, the options in the drop down disappear.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dropdown to update the preview in the editor. You can find it under tabs view. If you will change the selected value, the syntax highlight under #if #else updates

[image]